# creating a login page

Tags: vba, ms-access

i'm currently experiencing a problem when trying to create a login page for my users, its giving me a run time error '424' how can i go about using this? i'm creating a form in access 2010 and i'm new to this so all tips would be appreciated.

here is my code

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim rstUserPwd As Recordset
    Dim bFoundmatch As Boolean

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rstUserPwd = dbs.OpenRecordset("QryUserPwd")

    bFoundmatch = False

    If rstUserPwd.RecordCount > 0 Then    
        rstUserPwd.MoveFirst
        'Checks for matching records

        Do While rstUserPwd.EOF = False
            If rstUserPwd![UserName] = Form_Fromlogin.txtusername.Value And rstUserPwd![Password] = Form_Fromlogin.txtpassword.Value Then
                bFoundmatch = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            rstUserPwd.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    If bFoundmatch = True Then
        'open the next form and closes this one.
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmNavigation"
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect username or password, please try again"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why so complicated? If you can select a matched user name and password, the entry is valid. Because this is MS Access, it is all imaginary security. This is not a criticism of Access.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you could point to us the line where you get the runtime error.

424 is Object required so, judging from your code, it could be this line :

```
Set rstUserPwd = dbs.OpenRecordset("QryUserPwd")
```

or maybe this line :

```
If rstUserPwd![UserName] = Form_Fromlogin.txtusername.Value 
And rstUserPwd![Password] = Form_Fromlogin.txtpassword.Value Then
```

If it's the first case, make sure the query is saved with the exact name in Access.

If it's the second case, I would consider changing the references to the recordset's fields as follows:

```
    rstUserPwd("[UserName]") 
    rstUserPwd("[Password]")
```